# How to select only inline style in html file using regex?

Tags: regex

I tried to select the inline styles in p tag and div tag only. But no need to select td,  inline styles

regex   `style=[\"\w\d\.\:\-\'\s\#\;]+`

Input:

```
<p class="Test"><span style="font-family:Verdana">?</span><span style="font:7.0pt 'Times New Roman'">&#xa0; </span><span>AAA</span></p>

<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse:collapse; margin-left:0pt">
<tr>
<td style="border-bottom-color:#808080; border-bottom-style:solid; border-bottom-width:0.5pt; border-top-color:#808080; border-top-style:solid; border-top-width:0.5pt; padding-bottom:2.85pt; padding-top:2.85pt; vertical-align:top; width:81pt">
<p class="Tabelle" style="margin-top:3pt; margin-bottom:3pt"><span style="font-family:Tahoma; font-size:9pt">Detail</span></p>
</td>
```

output:

`style="margin-top:3pt; margin-bottom:3pt` in p tag

Note:
I need to select only p tag, div tag tags inline styles.

Comment: Try to show an example of what output should look like.

Comment: What after selecting? Remove?

Comment: replace the empty string@MYGz

Comment: Which language do you use for the regex (javascript, php, c#, etc.)?

Comment: @user6479492 You are not very specific. Do you want to select `style` in `<p>` and `<div>` tags exclusively? Do you want to select it in `<span>` or other tags inside `<p>` or `<div>` tags also?

Comment: i am using C#@Niitaku

Comment: Expect table tag , td tag and tr tag@MYGz

Comment: If I understand you well, you want to select the `style`attribute of `<p>` and `<div>` tags, only if they are nested within `<table>`, `<tr>` or `<td>` tag, is that correct?

Comment: Yes..that's it.@Niitaku

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

Find by:

```
(<(?:p|div)[^<]*)(style="[^"]*")([^>]*>)
```

replace by:

```
$1$3
```

C# Code Sample:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string pattern = @"(<(?:p|div)[^<]*)(style=""[^""]*"")([^>]*>)";
        string substitution = @"$1$3";
        string input = @"<p class=""Test""><span style=""font-family:Verdana"">?</span><span style=""font:7.0pt 'Times New Roman'"">&#xa0; </span><span>AAA</span></p>

<table cellspacing=""0"" cellpadding=""0"" style=""border-collapse:collapse; margin-left:0pt"">
<tr>
<td style=""border-bottom-color:#808080; border-bottom-style:solid; border-bottom-width:0.5pt; border-top-color:#808080; border-top-style:solid; border-top-width:0.5pt; padding-bottom:2.85pt; padding-top:2.85pt; vertical-align:top; width:81pt"">
<p class=""Tabelle"" style=""margin-top:3pt; margin-bottom:3pt""><span style=""font-family:Tahoma; font-size:9pt"">Detail</span></p>
</td>

";
        RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.Multiline;

        Regex regex = new Regex(pattern, options);
        string result = regex.Replace(input, substitution);

        System.Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
}
```

[Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/aqQaWg/5)

You get yoru data in group 1

Comment: If any possible to select group 1 only @Maverick_Mrt

Comment: nope, what language are you using ? I can show how to get the group 1

Comment: I am using C# to replace the group1@Maverick

Comment: replace by what empty ?